# Terms that appear in the RG flow with regards to symmetries of the Lagrangian

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, renormalization, effective-field-theory

Consider a theory with Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}$ with a global $U(1)$ symmetry, and consider adding a deformation

$$\mathcal{L}_g = g \mathcal{O}(x)$$

which breaks the $U(1)$ symmetry explicitly. However, equivalently we could see this as having added a term

$$\mathcal{L'}_g = g(x) \mathcal{O}(x),$$

where now $g(x)$ is treated as a background field with appropriate charge such that $\mathcal{L}_g$ respects the $U(1)$ symmetry. Our initial deformation $\mathcal{L}_g$ can be seen as the same as $\mathcal{L'}_g$ where the field $g(x)$ takes a constant value $g(x)= \langle g \rangle$ that breaks the $U(1)$ symmetry, like a vev that spontaneously breaks it.

Will $\mathcal{L+L_g}$ evolve under the RG flow such that the $U(1)$ symmetry respected?

Comment: The word you are looking for is "spurion". That's exactly what you are describing